# What are the advantages and disadvantages of building a tablet / smartphone app in html 5?

Tags: html, tablet, smartphone

I wrote a kids' storybook/picture book which I want to get made into an app for iPad, iPhone, and other tablets and smartphones.

I don't know much on the tech side of this.

I heard that it could be a good idea to create the app in html 5 and then 'wrap' it for each different device, rather than creating the app as a native app for each different device.

Are there any disadvantages to doing it this way?

I guess the main advantage of doing it this way, is that it's more efficient to build the app for lots of devices, but are there any other advantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advantages**:

- "Write once and run anywere " is the main advantage of writing your mobile/table app using HTML5.
- Build your app with open web standards to run on many platforms (e.g. Flash is a bad idea and even Adobe started supporting HTML5 in mobile devices over flash)
- You can easily find developers with HTML, CSS, Javascript knowledge or you may already have.

**Disdvantages**:

- Performance - Native application wins over HTML5 applications in this. But you don't need native performance for *all* applications. So its a disadvantage only in some cases.
- Look and feel - Native look and feel is better than HTML5 app in some cases.

You may check phonegap, senchatouch, titanium.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make money on your app it can be harder with an html5 app. The infrastructure like app store/marketplace/android market is not as good for html5 apps.